# How can I run "myfile.exe" as a standalone executable file without running "Startxwin" on Cygwin?

Tags: linux, cygwin, executable, x11

I have "myfile.exe" which is created in Cygwin. When you run it, a black window pops up and says:

Parsing ...

Parsing ...

.
.
.

Can't open Display!

So, I found out that I need to run this executable file through Cygwin and type in:

'startxwin'

and thereafter a white window pops up and from there I am able to run "myfile.exe" by type in:

'./myfile.exe'.

However, when I have the final version of "myfile.exe", I would like the end user be able to run it just by clicking it once and it runs the program!

In StackOverFlow I could not find a similar issue but my guts telling me that I might be able to make "startxwin" automatically built in somewhere in my Cygwin folder or find another solution!

So, in your opinion which of the following options is much more doable:

1. Write a piece of code that makes a "built-in" startxwin inside the Cygwin Folder and when you use "make all" it is automatically giving you this opportunity to make a standalone executable file?
2. Or There is another way of doing this such as finding another Linux compiler such as MinGW or so and try there?

****Please DO NOT suggest me to compile my files in Visual Studio or Windows based IDEs as the original files have used FLTK and they are Linux bases!

Comment: You could add `startxwin myfile.exe` to your .bash_profile ... then it should start whenever you open Cygwin. You would probably also want to add checks to make sure it is not already running.

Comment: Markku should I use if statement inside my '.bash_profile'? Or simply use startxwin myfile.exe?

Comment: It depends what you want. One possibility also is that you could put something like this in your .bash_profile:  `[ -e startMyFile ] && ./startMyFile`. Then put `startx myfile.exe` inside a file called `startMyFile`. The line in the .bash_profile will only execute the startMyFile script if it exists.

Comment: Markku, I want to have MyFile.exe run once it is clicked! So let's say I have the command line as you said:    [ -e startMyFile ] && ./startMyFile      However, I did not get the file that you mentioned about. you said: put startx myfile.exe inside a file called startMyFile   What file are you talking about?

Comment: I put the outline of the idea in an answer -- it is easier to read there. The answer does not use the startMyFile file, just .bash_profile and your executable.

Comment: Mark,Here is the code by giving you the link.[link](http://textuploader.com/6kuh)

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues to deal with:

1. Your executable must run within the Cygwin subsystem
2. Your executable also requires an X11 display

One way to deal with these, is to cause Cygwin to invoke startxwin and your program when it, itself, starts. Then, when you double-click the Cygwin desktop icon, your program also starts. To make this happen, you can add the following to your .bash_profile file inside Cygwin:

```
[ -e ~/myFile.exe ] && startxwin ~/myFile.exe
```

This says, if ~/myFile.exe exists, invoke `startxwin` (which starts X11) with `~/myFile.exe` as an argument. This tells `startxwin` to start `myFile.exe` once the X11 system is ready.

Comment: Markku, I am guessing that I put your command line in wrong place in the bash file or I have syntax error. Here is what I have added as you recommended: <code>[ -e ~/calibrator.exe ] && startxwin ~/calibrator.exe </code>

 
 </code>     I've added this at the bottom of '_bash_profile'. However there is also a line  which says:What do you think?

Comment: Pretty hard to diagnose that without more info.  Go into Cygwin, and type this `cat ~/.bash_profile`, then copy/paste the result here.

Comment: # User dependent .bash_profile file
# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi

# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#   PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# fi

# Set MANPATH so it includes users' private man if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/man" ]; then
#   MANPATH="${HOME}/man:${MANPATH}"
# fi

# Set INFOPATH so it includes users' private info if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/info" ]; then
#   INFOPATH="${HOME}/info:${INFOPATH}"
# fi
[ -e ~/calibrator.exe ] && startxwin ~/calibrator.exe

Comment: Okay, that does not render well in a comment. Try this: `[ -e "${HOME}/calibrator.exe" ] && startxwin "${HOME}/calibrator.exe"`. Then make sure that calibrator.exe is in the same directory as .bash_profile.

Comment: I did so. Still no progress! :(

Comment: What happens if you type this in Cygwin: `startxwin "${HOME}/calibrator.exe"`?

Comment: I mean type that on the Cygwin command line, and see if you get an error message.

Comment: Wow! Mark, now when I run Cygwin it will run the Calibrator.exe! But what if I want not to use Cygwin. Just by clicking exe file run it?

Comment: I mean is there any way to make calibrator.exe standalone?

Comment: If you compile it in Cygwin, you have to run it in Cygwin. There is a Windows version of FLTK, so you could try to compile your code with MinGW, but you will probably run into other issues as well if the code came from Linux.

Comment: But Mark, how did the primary creators of the exe file had a standalone executable file before? Even in windows when you compile a project in Visual Studio you will have a standalone executable file that you can run it on different platform I guess. So, you believe that there is no chance to have a standalone executable file?

Comment: I have no idea how they did it, I don't know anything about 'calibrator.exe'. There is certainly a way to create a standalone executable, either by porting to Windows/FLTK with MinGW, or possibly embedding the Cygwin runtime, but either of those options is likely to require substantially more effort. You might research those options, try one, and then post more specific questions when you run into problems.

Comment: Yes, I just started to work with MinGW. That might help! Might not! Also I am thinking of .dll files. Because they have .dll files + calibrator.exe. Even though when I use dependency walker it shows that Cygwin itself has all needed .dll files. I am not sure I can play with .dll files and make it work!